# GraphQLFederationModule healthcheck

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, nestjs

I'm learning nest.js and I have an issue I may not completely understand.

In our company we have dev-gateway which checks `MY_URL/.well-known/apollo/server-health` endpoint to be sure services are up before creating and then download schema from MY_URL. MY_URL is variable we pass to configuration.

So I need to have GET http://MY_URL/.well-known/apollo/server-health to return { status: pass } and POST http://MY_URL/ to return schema/be graphql endpoint.

If `path` in GraphQLFederationModule config is equal to `/` it works, but if I have path defined as `/graphql` then:

- GET http://MY_URL/.well-known/apollo/server-health returns { status: pass } and I think it's issue, I wanted graphql service under `/graphql` path
- GET http://MY_URL/graphql/.well-known/apollo/server-health is graphql endpoint and it return error (lack of query) and I think it should return { status: pass }
- GET http://MY_URL/graphql returns graphql enpoint which is OK

I prepared some minimal working version and I'm using:
"@apollo/federation": "^0.25.1",
"@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^7.10.3",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.22.2",
"graphql": "^15.5.0",
"graphql-tools": "^7.0.4",

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  GraphQLFederationModule,
  Query,
  Resolver,
  ResolveReference,
  Directive, Field, ID, ObjectType 
} from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('')
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  healthCheck() {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}

@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "_id")')
export class AdSpot {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  _id: string;

  @Field((type) => String)
  name: string
}

@Resolver((of) => AdSpot)
export class CatResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [AdSpot], { name: 'adSpots' })
  async getAdSpots() {
    return [];
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [CatResolver],
})
export class CatsModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    CatsModule,
    GraphQLFederationModule.forRoot({
      include: [CatsModule],
      path: '/graphql',
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      sortSchema: true,
      playground: true,
      disableHealthCheck: false,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}

async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(3010);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('-------------------------------------');
    console.log(err);
  }
}

bootstrap();
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss some configuration or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative path i.e

```
typePaths: ['**/*.graphql'],
```

In Your case

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CatsModule,
    GraphQLFederationModule.forRoot({
      include: [CatsModule],
      typePaths: ['**/*.graphql'],
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      sortSchema: true,
      playground: true,
      disableHealthCheck: false,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
```

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm sorry for stupid question, but I don't have problem with `typePaths` but with `path` and I'm not sure how I can use `*` in graphql path.

Comment: Try this :  path: '***/* *.graphql',

Comment: Bill, I'm not trying to change ANY file path (and '*/graphql' is path to file), because I'm going code-first. How this could work?